# How to load the content of a tab delimited text file into a 2D list of strings?

Tags: vb.net, string, list, text-files

I can't seem to figure out how to load a tab separated text file into a 2D list of strings in VB.net. I have found a couple of solutions on the net, but the number of columns were hard coded. The number of columns in my case will change. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by reexamining your approach.  Each field represents a bit of data; create a class to store those bits together as an object, then a `List(Of thatClass)` to store the "lines".  Much easier and more efficient than an array.  Then just modify one of those "other solutions" to fit your needs

Comment: But the number of columns is different, sometimes I have 6 columns, 8 or 10 up to 15. I am not sure how a 2D array of primitives is less efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Dim wordsArray as New List(Of List(Of String))
Using sr as new io.StreamReader("filename")
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        wordsArray.Add(sr.ReadLine.Trim().Split(CChar(vbTab)).ToList)
    End While
End Using
```